# How to record qualitative variable with over 100 dummies to several levels as quantitative in SAS

Tags: sas, statistics

I am working with SAS and want to record variable which with over 50+ different qualitative dummies. For example, the state of the U.S.

In this case, I just want to reduce them into 4 or 5 levels dummy as quantitative variable.

I get several ideaS, for example to use if/else statement, however, the problem is that i have to write down and specify each of area name in SAS and the code looks like super heavy.

Is there any other ways to do that without redundant code? Or to avoid write each specific name of variable? In SAS.

Any ideas are appreciated!!

Comment: This ends up just being a lookup problem. At some point you have to define how you want them grouped, and then apply the groups. It's actually easier to create 49 dummy variables cause you don't have to think there.

Comment: Please post your actual attempts in the future.

Comment: @Reeza Thank you for your response. I did it in the same way as your first method, by using the IF/THEN statement. But your second method is brand new for me. It seems like hard to avoid typing the words from variable...

Comment: Well yes, if there’s not a clear logical order the computer can only do what you tell you it. If there’s some sort of logic (eg order of vars, such as groups of 5, or alphabetically) you have other options.

Answer (score 1):

**Method 1:**

Use IN, but you still have to list the variables. You can also do it via a format, but you have to define the format first anyways.

```
if state in ('AL', 'AK', 'AZ' ... etc) then state_group = 1;
else if state in ( .... ) then state_group = 2;
```

**Method 2:**

For a format, you create format using PROC FORMAT and then apply it.

```
proc format;
value $ state_grp_fmt
'AL', 'AK', 'AZ' = 1
'DC', 'NC' = 2 ;
run;
```

And then you can use it with a PUT statement.

```
State_Group = put(state, state_grp_fmt);
```

Comment: Brilliant response